# How to pass a function with parameters from view to template in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am passing a function from views.py to a template in Django. This function takes a date argument and returns the difference between it and today's date

```
views.py:

def days_until(date1):
    td = datetime.date.today
    temp = date1 - td
    return temp.days

def index(request):
    entries = Entry.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'entries' : entries, 'days_until' : days_until})

index.html:

{% for entry in entries %}

<div> {{ days_until(entry.date) }} </div>

{% endfor %}
```

This code doesn't work and returns this error:

> Could not parse the remainder: '(entry.pwExp)' from 'days_until(entry.pwExp)'

I'm assuming that I am not calling days_until incorrectly. How should I be passing entry.date into this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all what you need is a django template custom filter:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-template-tags/

create my_filters.py in templatetags folder in your app.
write this:

```
from django import template
import datetime

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='days_until')
def days_until(date):
    td = datetime.date.today
    return (date - td).days
```

in template:

```
{% load my_filters %}
{% for entry in entries %}

<div> {{ days_until|entry.date }} </div>

{% endfor %}
```

other possibility is - you can use Jinja Template manager.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2

there you can made python calls in templates.

But this all is wrong. you can made it before, in context creation:

```
entries = (days_until(entry.date) for entry in Entry.objects.all())
```

and after that in template:

```
{% for entry in entries %}
<div> {{ entry }} </div>
{% endfor %}
```

This is much better: low code and it is faster.